# How re-create Gamespot sticky navigation menu?

Tags: javascript, css, menu, nav

Anyone knows what `.js` or `.css` was used on [THIS](http://www.gamespot.com/) menu?

Exactly, how to add a logo change when scrolling?

Comment: Right mouse click and "View Source". Or google "js menu plugins"

Answer (score 0):

It's done using jquery, for example:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
         $('.menu').addClass('somecustomclass');
     }
});
```

Using it you can add a class that specifies another background image for the container and much more